# Add parent entity id in custom form

Tags: php, forms, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am using this custom form generated by console crud generator:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SubtaskType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')->add('description')        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Subtask'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_subtask';
    }


}
```

After generating the crud I added a bidirectional association between `Task` and `Subtask`, and I modified the controller accordingly. So when I add a `Subtask` it should always be added to the `Task` that is in the url. Here is how it looks like with routes in annotations:

```
/**
 * Subtask controller.
 *
 * @Route("/task/{taskId}/subtask")
 */
class SubtaskController extends Controller
{
.
.
.
    /**
     * Creates a new subtask entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="subtask_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request, $taskId)
    {
        $subtask = new Subtask();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\SubtaskType', $subtask);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($subtask);
            $em->flush($subtask);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('subtask_show', array('id' => $subtask->getId(), 'taskId' => $taskId));
        }

        return $this->render('subtask/new.html.twig', array(
            'subtask' => $subtask,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'taskId'   => $taskId
        ));
    }
.
.
.
}
```

At this moment This code inserts a row in the `subtask` table successfully with a `null` value for `task_id` (the foreign key for task).

How can I adapt this code so that it inserts the right `task_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the work around that I found:

I added manually this method in the `Subtask` Entity

```
/**
 * Set task
 *
 * @param Task $task
 *
 * @return Subtask
 */
public function setTask($task)
{
    $this->task = $task;

    return $this;
}
```

And than I modified the `newAction` method in this way:

```
/**
 * Creates a new subtask entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="subtask_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request, $taskId)
{
    $subtask = new Subtask();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $task = $em->getReference('AppBundle\Entity\Task', $taskId);
    $subtask->setTask($task);
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\SubtaskType', $subtask);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($subtask);
        $em->flush($subtask);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('subtask_show', array('id' => $subtask->getId(), 'taskId' => $taskId));
    }

    return $this->render('subtask/new.html.twig', array(
        'subtask' => $subtask,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'taskId'   => $taskId
    ));
}
```

This gives me the expected result.

Any better way to achieve this?